# tub cartridge stops are failing

Tags: bathtub, cartridge

My kids have (twice now) managed to crank the handleset so hard that the cartridge (it's a Pfister 9740640) stops fail, allowing the handle to go past the stops. You can still feel the stops, but now that they're worn down (even on the brand new cartridge), the handle doesn't stop there reliably.

Could the handleset be causing this? I guess my next step is to replace it, but, I mean, it's just a handle. The current handle is perpendicular to the tap, so you can get a ton of leverage if you try (and teenagers, well, try). Maybe I should switch it out for a knob-style?

Or... perhaps I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: Having the teenagers pay the plumber to come out and fix the problem should put a stop to them from trying to determine how much leverage they can apply. Strikes me as a good opportunity to teach them that bad decisions have consequences.

Comment: Beyond that, it might help to [edit] your question to add some pics that show what's going on here - someone may have a cheap fix if you don't want the kids to learn.

Comment: I’ll add pictures if I pull the handle off again. But the gist of the question is — should cartridge stops be failing that easily? I’d think they’d be a little more robust generally.

Comment: Oh, and Freeman — no plumber involved to swap a cartridge. It is a $40 part though.

Comment: You wouldn't be asking here if you were just going to hire a plumber, but doing so and having the kids pay for it... ;) Also, I haven't a clue as to the answer to your question.